# iTunes/Mp3-Player and actual multi-tagging of MP3s

Tags: itunes, id3-tag

I search for a software to allow multi-tagging.
Meaning, i want to add more than one genre to a song/album to be able to easily access specific songs i.e. ("female singer, jazz" or "duet, jazz") which i can not realy do by choosing just one genre.

Is there an option to do this with iTunes?
If not, is there a player able to do this?
Maybe even with pandora/last.fm/musicbrains interface so i don't even have to tag all the songs myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a thorough analyse of the topic, read [Ways to store multiple genres in your digital music](http://www.blisshq.com/music-library-management-blog/2011/03/12/multiple-genres-in-mp3s/), where Dan says:

> MP3. MP3s (or rather, the ID3 tagging format used by MP3s) don't support multiple tags for genre. Instead you must useone existing tag and use a delimiter character to separate the genres within that tag.

If you use iTunes player, I'd recommend to use the `Grouping` tag for that purpose.

Now, can you do that automatically ?
As you pointed out, [Last.fm](http://lasft.fm) offers an interface to retrieve tags for songs.
And [bdefore](https://github.com/bdefore/iTunes-Multi-Genre-Tagger) used that API to develop an iTunes Multi-Genre Tagger (description blog post [here](http://bcdef.org/itunes-multi-genre-tagger/), last version of the script [here](https://github.com/bdefore/iTunes-Multi-Genre-Tagger)). I think that's the tool you're after.

Comment: Thanks a lot for so much Information! I will look into that!